# basic html/css float/division issue

Tags: html, css

this might be a stupid question but I'm stuck and need some help. I'm practicing float and div, and I managed to create this simple page but when I zoom out to 90% the box on the far right falls down to below. I tried to debug but I can't figure out what is causing this problem--could anyone help me? Below is the link to the mentioned page.

http://ratiayson.dothome.co.kr/day14_0225/coffeebeans2.html

Comment: next time, add code example. You fixed the issue on the website now, and it swill be difficult for future viewer to understand what was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you have given width: `876px` on the `.container`.
Bump it up to `900px` and it will work.

Comment: this solved the problem! Thank you so much! I should think more when I debug next time. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: done! Thanks for letting me know. I'm fairly new to this community...

Answer (score 0):

**PIECE OF ADVICE**

Hellow @Ratia, using float is a good idea, but using grid and flex based layouts is the best idea.

Float will require you to put lots of code to do a basic thing, Grid and Flex will do everything for you. Even auto responsiveness(Which is what you asked there above)

I urge you to use grid or flex...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I haven't gotten so far with the basics of html and css but I'll try to learn those as my next step. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Float Layout</title>
      <style>
         *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
         a{ text-decoration: none; color:#333;}
         li{list-style: none;}
         img{border: none;}
         body{font-size: 12px; font-family: 'sans-serif';}
         .header{
         margin:auto;
         width:876px;
         }
         h1{
         font-size: 30px;
         font-weight: 900;
         width:876px;
         }
         h2{
         font-size: 30px;
         font-weight: 900;
         font-family: sans-serif;
         color:saddlebrown;
         padding-bottom: 30px;
         text-align: center;
         }
         
         
          .container {
            display: table;
            border-spacing: 10px; 
            margin:auto;
            width: 876px;
            clear:both;
        }
         .container div{
             border: 1px dotted brown;
             padding: 15px;
         }
         
        .Column {
            display: table-cell;
            }
         
         
         
         .container img{
             padding-bottom: 30px;
             /*overflow:hidden;*/ 
         }
         
         p{
         font-size:14px;
         font-weight: 600;
         padding-bottom: 50px;
         }
         .container span{
         font-size:16px;
         background-color:goldenrod; 
         }
         .bottomBox{
         background-color: #333;
         clear:both;
         margin:auto;
         width:874px;
         height:50px;
         color:azure;
         text-align: center;
         font-size: 16px;
         padding-top:30px;
         width:874px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="8.871.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
      <div class="header">
         <h1>coffee beans</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="liberica Column">
            <h2>Coffee Liberica</h2>
            <img src="http://ratiayson.dothome.co.kr/day14_0225/images/bean1.jpeg" alt="">
            <p>Desde 1835 se comenzó a cultivar comercialmente <span>el grano de café en Colombia13</span>​ en Salazar de las Palmas, Norte de Santander. Gran parte del incentivo a la producción se le atribuye a Francisco Romero, sacerdote de la época que imponía a los feligreses de la población, durante la confesión, la penitencia de sembrar café. Esto fue un gran impulso para la propagación del cultivo del grano en esa zona del país. </p>
         </div>
         <div class="arabica Column">
            <h2>Coffee Arabica</h2>
            <img src="https://minisoft.com.bd/uploads/portfolios/minisoft.png" alt="">
            <p>Desde 1835 se comenzó a cultivar comercialmente <span>el grano de café en Colombia13</span>​ en Salazar de las Palmas, Norte de Santander. Gran parte del incentivo a la producción se le atribuye a Francisco Romero, sacerdote de la época que imponía a los feligreses de la población, durante la confesión, la penitencia de sembrar café. Esto fue un gran impulso para la propagación del cultivo del grano en esa zona del país. </p>
         </div>
         <div class="robusta Column">
            <h2>Coffee Robusta</h2>
            <img src="http://ratiayson.dothome.co.kr/day14_0225/images/bean1.jpeg" alt="">
            <p>Desde 1835 se comenzó a cultivar comercialmente <span>el grano de café en Colombia13</span>​ en Salazar de las Palmas, Norte de Santander. Gran parte del incentivo a la producción se le atribuye a Francisco Romero, sacerdote de la época que imponía a los feligreses de la población, durante la confesión, la penitencia de sembrar café. Esto fue un gran impulso para la propagación del cultivo del grano en esa zona del país. </p>
         </div>
         <!--<div class='bottomBox'>
            <span class='bottomText'><p>유명하고 비싼 커피보다 신선한 커피가 맛있습니다</p></span>
            </div>-->
      </div>
      <div class="bottomBox">
         coffee beans
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```